# Is my logic correct? - main view and output view

Tags: android, android-activity

I am confused here.

What my program do:

- displays a view(**main** layout) that allows user to enter some values(contains TextViews, EdiTexts, a  single Button)
- when button is pressed, it contacts server and fetches data (HTTP POST - uses AsyncTask & get result)
- now format this data(result from server) and display it in another layout(**output** layout)
- when user presses back button, it goes back to main page(**main** layout) so to allow user to enter new data and fetch output from server again

What I have done:

- i have created an activity called "MyApp"
- created two layouts - main & output
- created button handler code for "Submit" button (of main layout) to start AsyncTask and to do HTTP posting and fetching of data
- in onPostExecute(), i have written code to display **output** layout (`setContentView(R.layout.output);`) and to create TextViews in it and setText to set text.

After reading some articles i find i have to use separate activity to display output. Pass data from fetch operation of my main activity to second activity(output activity) and format it there and write code for button click handler to get back to main activity.
To send data from main activity to output activity, i should use `Bundle`. Correct ? Is anything to take care other than this ? Please guide me.

Comment: You might need a progress dialog to display while the data is being fetched from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In onPostExecute() call new activity with your data.

i.e., 
Intent i = new Intent(firstactivity.this,secondactivity.class);
i.putExtra("key","value");
startActivity(i);
 and in the second activity you can read value as below

value = getIntent().getStringExtra("key"); // if in first activity value is string 
value = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("key"); // if in first activity value is boolean 

Try this....
```

Comment: if your value is of string type then if it is boolean then it will be getBooleanExtra(). If you get it tell

Answer (score 0):

In mainActivity, you set an intent to call outputActivity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

You add your EditText fields to the intent like so:

```
intent.putExtra("aNameYouInvent", value);
```

Then you launch it:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

You should put the AsyncTask in outputActivity, it will fetch your http data without hogging the UI responsiveness. 
To get your data back, you do

```
value = getIntent().getIntentExtra("aNameYouInvent");
```

Last, you do not need a software back button, unless you wish to, the hardware button will work.

Best regards

Comment: it says `getIntentExtra()` is undefined